# Is $0$ matrix diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

---

Is $0_{n\times n}$ matrix diagonalizable?

So, I need $AM=GM$. I can find $AM=n$ of $0$. But what is $GM$ of $0$?

AM=algebraic multiplicity, GM=geometric multiplicity

Comment: The zero matrix is already a diagonal matrix.

Comment: @cello AM=algebraic multiplicity, GM=geometric multiplicity

Comment: @DietrichBurde what abt digonal? How can I argue that GM=n for 0?

Comment: You need *no* computation to show that a diagonal matrix is diagonalizable, because *every* matrix is similar to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is diagonalizable. It is already a diagonal matrix, since it has zero entries everywhere (remember that a diagonal matrix must have zeros everywhere except on the main diagonal)

Comment: but how can I argue that GM=n for 0?

Comment: $\Bbb R^n$ (or $\Bbb C^n$) is the $n$-dimensional eigenspace for $0$ associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda = 0$.

Comment: ok, I am explaining, tell me if I am wrong or right please @Omnomnomnom : dimension of the eigen vector of $0=n-$ dimension of the null space of $\mathbb{R}^n=n-0=n$.

Comment: Your explanation is nonsense.  An eigenvector is a vector; what is the "dimension of the eigenvector"?  A matrix has a nullspace (i.e. a kernel), but does the "null space of $\Bbb R^n$" refer to?